# Automating SSH authentication to GitHub - what should ~/.ssh/config file look like?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys, github, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to automate logins to GitHub using a private key, so that I can do "git pull/add/commit/push" from a BASH script.  If I put this in ~/.ssh/config, it works:

```
Hostname github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mygitkey.pem
```

Unfortunately, this causes ***all*** SSH connections to be routed to Github.com, which I don't want.

So I tried this:

```
Host GitHub
   Hostname github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mygitkey.pem
```

But this causes the "user" and "identityFile" options to be ignored when connecting to GitHub.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762034/push-to-github-without-password-using-ssh-key

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
Host github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mygitkey.pem
```

(Possibly the `User` if it serves a purpose for you, but the remotes in your repositories presumably already say `git@github.com`, which would make it pointless to specify the `User` here too)

The config in the question looks like it should technically work, but you would have to change all references (like the remotes in your repositories) from `github.com` to `GitHub`.

Comment: Yeah I already tried that, no luck.  Running`ssh -v git@github.com` I see it does connect to GitHub, but only tries the default private keys (i.e. `~/.ssh/id_rsa`) but not the  `~/.ssh/mygitkey.pem`     My OpenSSH client is 7.2p2 which is getting quite old, so perhaps this is is the issue